# how to format a USB-Drive with fdisk?

Tags: fdisk

I want to format a USB-Drive (/dev/sdc) and make multiple partitions each of a different type using fdisk. My fdisk uses sectors(not cylinders) to create a new partition.
/dev/sdc1 <- NTFS  (10GiB)
/dev/sdc2 <- Fat32 (04GiB)

Can someone please provide the step by step method to be used in a terminal ?

http://oi67.tinypic.com/34h9v1z.jpg
http://oi68.tinypic.com/2954t5i.jpg

Comment: Read `man fidsk`

Comment: Sorry but got no clues as to how to allocate the size using sectors and no clues are there in man fdisk also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a calculator written in C-Language

20971520 is equal to 10GiB
As shown in the picture, 512 bytes is equal to one sector.